# SQL Server encryption using self signed SSL certificate. Querying from ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: .net, sql-server, encryption, ssl, self-signed

I've created a self-signed cert for testing encryption between my web application and the SQL Server.

When attempting to query the database using "Encrypt=Yes;" in the connection string, I receive the following message:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

**Background**
I received an identical message when first attempting an encrypted connection from management studio. This was resolved by installing the self-signed cert into my Trusted Certificate Authorities.

**Question**
Is there a way I can get ASP.NET to trust the certificate the same way my user account does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK the proper answer for this lay in adding the self-signed cert to the certificate store.

**The wrong way**
Installing the certificate by double-clicking the .cer file on the server
 - This adds the cert for the currently logged in user only, which is why impersonation worked in some cases.

**The right way**
Using CertMgr.exe to install the certificate.
 - You can find CertMgr.exe in a Windows SDK, or apparently in Visual Studio 2005's bin folder. It's not in VS2008.
 - You **must** run CertMgr.exe under a **Local Machine Administrator** account. A Domain account with local administrator privileges will not work
 - Run CertMgr.exe to add the certificate to the localmachine trustedpublishers stores, by running both of the following commands:
 - `certmgr /add Your.Certificate.Filename.cer /s /r localmachine root`
 - `certmgr /add Your.Certificate.Filename.cer /s /r localmachine trustedpublisher`

Also note you can't use wildcards when referring to the certificate filename. (/add *.cer will fail.)

Answer (score 0):

Using impersonation works on my local development machine:
`<identity impersonate="true"/>` (in system.web of my web.config)

Thus ensuring that when ASP.NET connected to the database, it used my user credentials, and my user trusts the self-signed cert.

Note - this fails if attempting to view the site on the development server.

Comment: Is this an answer? If not, it's usually a good idea to delete this answer and post it as an update to your question. You can edit your own questions, you know.

Comment: It's an answer for some scenarios, but not a complete answer.